# MySQL - "Most social User" with the most comments in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables of concern - 'videoComments', 'storyComments'.

I need to find the 'posterID' that has the most entries in `videoComments` and `storyComments`. Here's the code I have so far, but it only calls `videoComments`:

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT posterID 
                  FROM videoComments 
              GROUP BY posterID 
              ORDER BY COUNT(posterID) DESC LIMIT 1) ) AS mostSocialUser ";
```

How  do I pull it and compare the COUNT of posterID from both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.posterid,
          COUNT(y.posterid) + COUNT(z.posterid) AS numComments
     FROM (SELECT vc.posterid
             FROM VIDEOCOMMENTS vc
           UNION 
           SELECT sc.posterid
             FROM STORYCOMMENTS sc) x
LEFT JOIN VIDEOCOMMENTS y ON y.posterid = x.posterid
LEFT JOIN STORYCOMMENTS z ON z.posterid = x.posterid
 GROUP BY x.posterid
 ORDER BY numComments DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Joel Hackney: `x` is a derived table that contains a unique list of all the posters, because a poster might only exist in one of the two tables.  That list of users is then used to LEFT JOIN to the tables, in order to count respective comments.  The ORDER BY and LIMIT ensures that the single highest poster is returned, but that's not to say there couldn't be ties...

Comment: before yesterday, I didn't even know about nested statements, so this is all new and wonderful stuff to me… thank you for the explaination, and the answer, it works wonderfully - i don't care about ties, but I can see how that's a common next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT posterID FROM (
        SELECT posterID FROM videoComments 
        UNION 
        SELECT posterID FROM storyComments
    ) GROUP BY posterID 
      ORDER BY COUNT(posterID) DESC LIMIT 1
) AS mostSocialUser
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, Thanks bud, I was playing with UNION but no love… either way, your suggestion returns a mysql_error() = "Every derived table must have its own alias." Any ideas?